# how to use multiple threads to draw multiple bitmaps on the canvas in surfaceview?

Tags: android, multithreading

I am developing a game in which I have to show multiple image moving in directions but one image cannot over lap other how can i achieve this. I think I should use multiple threads one thread for every image but when i try to initialize thread by sending it canvas using canvas it gives

```
error 01-11 17:18:15.409: E/AndroidRuntime(1046): java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: Thread already started.
```

How can I achive this. Can any body give me idea or some tutorial. Any help will be appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

Your error happens when you try to start an already started thread. You don't need to have multiple threads. One thread for all your drawing is more than enough.

I have written a tutorial series for introduction into android 2d drawing. I recommend you to start with the [second part that introduce the thread usage](http://www.droidnova.com/2d-tutorial-series-part-ii,772.html).

Comment: Sir I have already created game I have put in touch events but I am not able to remove overlapping of images thanks

Comment: Can you provide an image that shows your overlapping and what it should look like? Also have you stepped through the other parts of the series?

Comment: Sir in my my game the image should have some distance from each other but the images get overlapped each other at some time in my game the images are coming in down direction by using one coordinate of image suppose y but some times two images overlapped as show in this link http://www.droidnova.com/2d-tutorial-series-part-v,848.html

Comment: Than you need to implement a collision detection (done later in the series, too) and you need to define what should happen when they collide. Without more information from you and more some code, I can't help (I don't even know what kind of game do you develop).

Comment: Sir I have not solved the problem In my some of fruits coming down of the screen but there must be gap between two fruits can you suggest me how I can probably maintain gap. and Thanks for help

Comment: Get the position of the items and calculate the x and y coordinates for the new fruit. This is plain math so just try to get your head around it.